# Split a string based on spacein Hive

Tags: string, split, hive, apache-pig

This is the format of my CSV file:

```
Chevrolet C10,13.0,8,350.0,145.0,4055,12.0,76,US
Ford F108,13.0,8,302.0,130.0,3870,15.0,76,US
Dodge D100,13.0,8,318.0,150.0,3755,14.0,76,US
Honda Accord CVCC,31.5,4,98.00,68.00,2045,18.5,77,Japan
Buick Opel Isuzu Deluxe,30.0,4,111.0,80.00,2155,14.8,77,US
Renault 5 GTL,36.0,4,79.00,58.00,1825,18.6,77,Europe
Plymouth Arrow GS,25.5,4,122.0,96.00,2300,15.5,77,US
```

I want to split the first field like, 
Chevrolet C10 should be Chevrolet
Ford F108 should be Ford
Honda Accord CVCC should be Honda etc and then I will use the car name for further processing.

Comment: If you've made any attempt, please show the associated code.

Comment: I am using select rtrim(car) from cardetails; but not get success.

Comment: `split(model, ' ')[0]` ?  Also, why does this question have an `apache-pig` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in Pig

**Code :**

```
read = LOAD 'test.data' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, val1:long, val2:long, val3:long, val4:long, val5:long, val6:long, country:chararray);
sub_data = FOREACH read GENERATE SUBSTRING(name,0,(INDEXOF(name, ' ',0)))  AS (subname:chararray);
DUMP sub_data;
```

**Output :**

```
(Chevrolet)
(Ford)
(Dodge)
(Honda)
(Buick)
(Renault)
(Plymouth)
```

Comment: Now can i calculate AVG for other fileds as per subname?

Comment: r3 =foreach r2 generate group,AVG(r.mpg);  but it gives  error like Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.AVG as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1439102908813.log

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  case when MODEL like 'US % %' or MODEL like 'Europe % %'
        then regexp_extract(MODEL, '^([^ ]* [^ ]*) ', 1)
        when MODEL like '% %'
        then regexp_extract(MODEL, '^([^ ]*) ', 1)
        else MODEL
  end as BRAND
from WHATEVER
```

- Chevrolet C10 => Chevrolet
- US Honda Accord => US Honda
- Zorglub => Zorglub

Answer (score 0):

Use the below UDF -

```
substring_index(string A, string delim, int count)
```

[Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with the schema which you want for your table.

```
CREATE TABLE carinfo (carname STRING, val1 DOUBLE, val2 INT, val3 DOUBLE, val4 DOUBLE, val5 INT, val6 DOUBLE, val7 INT, country STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

load the data into the above table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/hivesamples/splitstr.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE carinfo;
```

Use `CTAS` to split the carname and get the brand name. This new table will have the same schema which you defined earlier.

```
CREATE TABLE modified_carinfo 
AS 
SELECT split(carname, ' ')[0] as carname, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 ,val6, val7, country 
FROM carinfo;
```